# SAS max value of a varible

Tags: dataset, sas, max, identity

I have a probably very simple question. I have a dataset with rows of different time periods. Every year a new time period is added to the dataset. 
In my dataset I have period 52, 53 and 54. Soon period 55 will be added.
In the code below I extract the rows from the latest period (54):

```
data new;
set old;
if period=54;
run;
```

Instead of hardcoding 54 (and soon 55) I want SAS to be able to identify the largest time period, so I don't have to correct the number every time a new period is added to the dataset. I have tried this:

```
data new;
set old;
if period=max(period);
run;
```

But the max function requires at least two arguments, and that is not what I want. Can anybody tell me which function to use instead?

Thanks a lot.

Kind regards Maria

Comment: Do you have just one row per time period or multiple rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a subset of old containing only the newest period can be done easily using PROC SQL:

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
  CREATE TABLE new AS
  SELECT *
    FROM old
   WHERE period = (SELECT MAX(period) FROM old);
QUIT;
```

Comment: Thanks - this works. Strange that you can use the max function like that in a sql and not in a a data step.

Comment: It is not that strange after all. MAX() in SQL is an aggregate function that works on a group of rows while MAX() in the datastep is adapted to its iterative nature and thus serves to find the greater of two values (one of whitch typically is the retained current maximum).

Answer (score 2):

You should consider keeping the last period in a data set so you don't have to calculate it each time you need to access the data.  Also create an INDEX on period to optimize retrieval.

```
25         options msglevel=i;
26         data example(index=(period)) lastperiod(keep=period);
27            set sashelp.class(in=in1) sashelp.class(in=in2) end=eof;
28            period = ifn(in1,54,55);
29            output example;
30            if eof then output lastperiod;
31            run;
32         
33         data _null_;
34            set period;
35            call symputx('LastPeriod',period);
36            run;
37         data period;
38            set example;
39            where period eq &lastperiod;
INFO: Index period selected for WHERE clause optimization.
40            run;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a macrovariable and a proc sql step to get the maxperiod, e.g.:

```
proc sql;
select max(period) into: maxp from old;
quit;

data new;
set old;
if period = "&maxp"; 
run;
```